# Shopping cart is the same for all users Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a project with laravel, and I want every user to have his own cart which means if user one adds item to cart, deletes or update it should only show in his account without affecting other users. For now when a user adds item or deletes it shows in all users.

I have tried some solutions from other source but didn't work.

**ProductController.php**

```
public function cart()
{
    return view('cart');
}

public function addToCart($id)
{
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $products = products_model::where('user_id', $userId)->find($id); 

    if(!$products) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $cart = session()->get('cart');

    // if cart is empty then this the first product
    if(!$cart) {

        $cart = [
            $id => [
                "pro_name" => $products->pro_name,
                "quantity" => 1,
                "pro_price" => $products->pro_price,
                "image" => $products->image
            ]
        ];

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()
                    ->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    }

    // if cart not empty then check if this product exist then increment quantity
    if(isset($cart[$id])) {

        $cart[$id]['quantity']++;

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()
                    ->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');

    }

    // if item not exist in cart then add to cart with quantity = 1
    $cart[$id] = [
        "pro_name" => $products->pro_name,
        "quantity" => 1,
        "pro_price" => $products->pro_price,
        "image" => $products->image
    ];

    session()->put('cart', $cart);

    return redirect()->back()
                ->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
}

public function update(Request $request)
{
    if($request->id and $request->quantity)
    {
        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        $cart[$request->id]["quantity"] = $request->quantity;

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        session()->flash('success', 'Cart updated successfully');
    }
}

public function remove(Request $request)
{
    if($request->id) {

        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        if(isset($cart[$request->id])) {

            unset($cart[$request->id]);

            session()->put('cart', $cart);
        }

        session()->flash('success', 'Product removed successfully');
    }
}
```

I tried to add these lines (add to cart) but isn't working.

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
$products = products_model::where('user_id', $userId)- >find($id);
```

Comment: Vote down without any reason?

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you can do. Its called **Replication**.

Just add one more field like userID in Products table and save users id on it.

To shown products to all users simply put top id(first id, probably system admin id)

So everytime when you want show, edit, update or delete you simply do with product id as well as user id.

Hope this will works.